# Vimeo video upload fails 1/10 times using Dio package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, vimeo-api, dio, flutter-http

I am using the POST method to upload video file from Flutter App using the [Dio](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio) package. Vimeo's POST method first generates a link for us to upload the video to. The video is uploaded successfully most of the time. Every once in a while, it fails (like 1/10).

[image]

To Test if this is an issue on Vimeo's server I tried uploading the video from POSTMAN, 20/20 (all of them) times it uploaded successfully. So I am assuming there is something wrong with the DIO Package?

I have also posted this issue in the DIO's github issues:
https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/1535#issue-1328014439

Upload video code:

```
 if (url != null) {
    print('upload link is not null!');
    Strings.videoURL = url;
    print('upload url is <>:');
    print(Strings.videoURL);
    try {
      Dio uploadVideoDio = new Dio();
      uploadVideoDio.options.headers["authorization"] = dotenv.env['VIMEO_ACCESS_TOKEN'];
      uploadVideoDio.options.headers["content-type"] = "application/json";
      uploadVideoDio.options.headers["accept"] = "application/json";

      var formData = FormData.fromMap({
        "file_data": await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path)
      });

     await uploadVideoDio.post(
        Strings.videoURL,
        data: formData,
        options: Options(
            followRedirects: false,
            responseType: ResponseType.json,
            validateStatus: (status) {
              print('status is :');
              print(status);
              // return status! < 500;
              if (status == 302) {
                uploadStatus = 'successful';
                return true;
              } else {
                return false;
              }
            }),
      );
      print('file upload called');
      print('upload status is ');
      print(uploadStatus);
      return uploadStatus;
    } on DioError catch (err) {
      print('error uploading actual video');
      print(err.toString());
      return uploadStatus;
    }
  } else {
    print('upload link is null');
    return uploadStatus;
  }
```

**Here's an update**

I got in touch with the Vimeo's support team and they are investigating the issue. Their response is that

> The "POST" method is not very reliable and you should use the TUS
> resumable approach.

I am about to test the stability of the `TUS` method and will update this post afterwards

Comment: When it fails, does it take longer to upload?

Comment: no it doesn't, all of my test videos were only around 7 seconds long

Comment: could it be related to file size?

Comment: no the file size is around 3.5 - 5 MB only, all my video files are in that range. It's very weird that most uploads are successful but only fails randomly. like  1 out of 10 times
I tried switching between WIFI and Mobile data, but it's the same